# How to UNNEST a variable list of JSON key value pairs values from a SQL column

Tags: sql, presto

I have a json dictionary in a cell of my table. The keys of the dictionary can be varied and I don't know the full list of them in advance.

How can I unnest the key value pairs?

*FWIW, I'm using Presto.*

```sql
with example(json_info) as (
    VALUES
    ('{"Key A": "ABC","Key B": "DEF", "Key C": "XYZ"}') 
)

select
    key
    , value
from example
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_PARSE(json_info)
                as ARRAY(ROW(key VARCHAR, value VARCHAR))
            )
    ) as x(key, value)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error which makes me think I'm on the wrong path.

> Cannot cast to array(row(type varchar,value varchar)). Expected a json array, but got { {"Key A": "123","Key B": "456", "Key C": "789"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the json object to `map(varchar, varchar)` and then [unnest](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest#unnest) it into a key and a value column:

```sql
...
UNNEST(
    CAST(json_parse(json_info) AS map(varchar, varchar))
) AS x(key, value)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to use a `map(varchar, varchar)`

```sql
with example(json_info) as (
    VALUES
    ('{"Key A": "123","Key B": "456", "Key C": "789"}') 
)

select
    key
    , value
from example
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(
            CAST(
                JSON_PARSE(json_info)
                as map(varchar, varchar)
            )
    ) as x(key, value)
```

which gave me this:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| Key A | ABC |
| Key B | DEF |
| Key C | XYZ |